# Backpropagation of wrongly (double) encoded CSV

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8, mojibake

I have a CSV file that someone encoded wrongly.

The file is a database of movies with corresponding actors. I downloaded it in order to practise some coding for the so called [Bacon number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Degrees_of_Kevin_Bacon).

It looks like this:

```
movieId,title,actors
(...)
61,Eye for an Eye (1996),(a ton of other actors)|Dolores VelÌÁzquez|(more actors)
59,The Confessional (1995),(a ton of other actors)|Richard FrÌ©chette|FranÌ¤ois Papineau|Marie Gignac|Normand Daneau|Anne-Marie Cadieux|Suzanne ClÌ©ment|Lynda Beaulieu|Pascal Rollin|Billy Merasty|Paul HÌ©bert|Marthe Turgeon|Adreanne Lepage-Beaulieu|AndrÌ©e-Anne ThÌ©roux-Faille|Rodrigue Proteau|Philippe Paquin|Pierre HÌ©bert|Nathalie D'Anjou|Danielle Fichaud|Jules Philip|Jacques Laroche|Claude-Nicolas Demers|Jean-Philippe CÌ«tÌ©|Tristan Wiseman|Marc-Olivier Tremblay|Jacques Brouillet|Jean-Paul L'Allier|Denis Bernard|RenÌ©e Hudon|Serge Laflamme|Carl Mathieu
(...)
```

Now as you can see, instead of Umlauts and letters with accents (ÄÖÜ, É, À, Û etc.), the actors have a combination of other special characters instead.

Thanks to very helpful input on this question, we have established that this is indeed a case of [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

My goal is to programmatically fix the broken characters by decoding and encoding in the correct order.

Comment: Can you provide a clear list of the characters affected what they are now and what they should be in UTF-8 (with hex codes to avoid any ambiguity)? I expect that with a dozen or so concrete examples someone will be able to spot the pattern. Undoing it programmatically might be ambiguous if some mappings are many to one.

Comment: Attempting to re-imagin the "usual" mishandlings didn't come up with any combination that produces this specific output, but it *certainly* looks like a traditional "UTF-8 bytes were wrongly decoded with a 8bit encoding" problem. I just don't know what 8bit encoding.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinBrown, I added some more examples in the post.

Comment: It looks like the 8bit encoding Joachim speaks about displays `Ì` for byte `0xc3`. Unfortunately, no 8bits encoding I am used to match here...

Comment: If the number of problematic sequences is limited, you might be better off just hard-coding a "fixing table".

Comment: @JoachimSauer thanks, that was also my initial idea. The problem is that the CSV is very large (thousands of long lines), impossible to inspect manually. So there are some very niche cases, like the upside down exclamation mark, that occur maybe 1-3 times. I spotted that exclamation mark by accident, but there may be other cases that I'd miss. If those are encoded by 3 symbols, I will then wrongly encode 2 of them (the Ì plus the next one after that), instead of the full one, creating more, new problems. Therefore, I would like to avoid a table like that.

Comment: You face a **double** [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python*): `'FrÌ©chette|FranÌ¤ois'.encode( 'cp1252').decode( 'mac-romanian').encode( 'cp1252').decode( 'utf-8')` returns `'Fréchette|François'`.  Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share where the `csv` file comes from (i.e. how it is created), as well as how do you read it…

Comment: I guess one option is to take the correct raw text samples and apply every pair of character page transforms that you can think of to it and hope that one of them gives you  Ì for byte 0xc3 and so is a match. Otherwise I think @Joachim Sauers idea is probably the most likely to succeed (even if you have to do it a few times when new infrequent faults come to light). I suspect the odd one may not be cleanly fixable.

Comment: @JosefZ thank you so much! I was able to ALMOST fix everything! I have updated the question with my new information

Comment: Again. Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular,  share where the `csv` file comes from (i.e. **how it is created**; please provide a link to `csv` file if you can…), as well as **how do you read it**…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what comes closest to the solution (provided by JosefZ):

> You face a double mojibake case (example in Python): 'FrÌ©chette|FranÌ¤ois'.encode( 'cp1252').decode( 'mac-romanian').encode( 'cp1252').decode( 'utf-8') returns 'Fréchette|François'.

Thanks to very helpful input on this question, we have established that this is indeed a case of [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

I have made progress with the following configuration (python):

1. Read the current csv with encoding not specified
2. encode('cp1252').decode('mac-roman').encode('cp1252').decode('iso-8859-16')
3. Write the result to new csv with encoding 'iso-8859-16' specified

With this configuration, many characters are fixed now, but some are still missing. I don't know if this means I have to decode and encode again (for a total of three times), or if I simply haven't found the correct configuration for a set of two dec-encs yet.

Here is a list of characters that are still broken after the above re-encode:

```
after re-encoding | just reading | desired outcome | notes
==============================================================================
�                | Ì            | Á               | the lower case á works;
�_               | Ì_           | ü               | the upper case Ü works
�_               | Ì_           | ä               | I can't confirm whether upper case Ä works
                                 | æ               | I can't confirm whether this exists, but I confirmed one upper case that works; it's possible the file uses 'ae' instead
                                 | œ               | I can't confirm whether any of this exists; it's possible the file uses 'oe' instead
�_               | Ì_           | í               | I can't confirm whether upper case Í works
�_               | Ì_           | ó               | the upper case Ó works
�_               | Ì_           | þ               | the upper case Þ doesn't exist, I think
```

Conclusion:

As you can see, both the reading of the file 'as is', as well as reading it after re-encoding, renders all missing characters as **the same** broken character, so it seems impossible to restore the original information for those (the information got lost in the process of Mojibake). I'm afraid that those lines would have to be fixed manually.